# Error in rooting Samsung Galaxy J2 (SMJ200G)

Tags: rooting, samsung

I want to root my Samsung Galaxy J2. But trying to install TWRP via Odin returns with "Fail".

On this XDA forum, https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/easy-to-root-galaxy-j200g-t3490324 , firmware model number should be J200GDDU1APB1. But my firmware model number is J200GDDU2APJ2.

Is there any way to change my model number to the one that is required?

Comment: @beeshyams The page has been removed. I am not able to access it. Is there any way to change the firmware??? Or downgrade as it is mentioned?

Comment: Maybe that is the same thing

Comment: A source for firmware??

Comment: Yes . Also you didn't search properly ( link had changed but it seems to be available for download on the site mentioned in OP https://boycracked.com/portfolio/samsung-galaxy-j2-sm-j200g-firmware-for-india/

Comment: Thanks for the link. How am I supposed to change firmware then? I man after downloading it.

Comment: Got it. It had installation guides. Cheers.

Comment: Flashing with Odin as mentioned in first para of OP and here is SamMobile site https://www.sammobile.com

Comment: Successful ????

Comment: @beeshyams Yes. But by TWRP

Comment: Good. You may like to self answer the question- it may help others in future

Comment: I am not sure how it failed earlier and succeeded now.